# Reduce multi-dimensional array of strings along axis in Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Does Numpy implement some function for reducing multi-dimensional array of strings? I know it offers some features for string concatenation of multiple arrays, but I haven't found anything about string reduction.

Let's say I have a 2-D array of strings:

```
np.array([['a', 'b', 'c'],['e','f','g']])
```

And I want to convert it to:

```
np.array(['a b c','e f g'])
```

Is there better way, than using a for loop, such as:

```
old_strings = np.array([['a', 'b', 'c'],['e','f','g']])
new_strings = np.array([])
for s in old_strings:
    new_strings = np.append(new_strings, (' '.join(s)))
```

Comment: Would all elements be single characters?

Comment: Is the space important, or would `''.join(s)` suffice?

Comment: @Divakar in this example they were, but the problem I am working on deals with strings of characters

Comment: @jpp not space precisely, but there is need for some delimiter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using regular string operations is better than using `np.char.join`.

```
>>> arr = np.array([['a', 'b', 'c'],['e','f','g']])
>>> np.array([' '.join(i) for i in arr])
array(['a b c', 'e f g'], dtype='<U5')
```

Will be faster than `np.char.join`

```
%timeit np.array([' '.join(i) for i in arr])
8.69 µs ± 30 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit np.char.join(' ', arr)
14.6 µs ± 86.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

On a much larger array:

```
arr = np.repeat(arr, 10000).reshape(-1, 3)

%timeit np.array([' '.join(i) for i in arr])
54.2 ms ± 596 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit np.char.join(' ', arr)
72.3 ms ± 2.36 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: It's actually kinda worse, `arr = np.array([['a', 'b', 'c'],['e','f','g']]); np.char.join(' ', arr)` does not even _work_... you have to force NumPy to consider it an array of lists to get the same result.

Comment: (if you do have an array of lists of strings, which already involves some overhead if need to create it from the original array of strings, then the performance seems to be the same for both methods...)

Answer (score 2):

This is a way you can sort of force the NumPy API to do this, although it probably will not be too different from doing it yourself:

```
import numpy as np

# Make one-dimensional array of lists of strings
a = np.array([None, None])
a[0] = ['a', 'b', 'c']
a[1] = ['e', 'f', 'g']
# Join
print(np.char.join(' ', a))
>>> ['a b c' 'e f g']
```

Comment: thanks for answer! although it answers my question, I chose @user3483203 's answer, because it also brings insight to different, probably more optimal solution