# Join array of strings/chars into single string with separator [without using comprehension, map, etc.]

Tags: python, arrays, string, pandas, numpy

Let's say I have an array like this:

```
>>> x = np.array([['Happy','New','Year'],['Stack','Over','flow']])
>>> x
array([['Happy', 'New', 'Year'],
       ['Stack', 'Over', 'flow']], dtype='<U5')
```

I want to join each element in each row, so something like this:

```
[['HappyNewYear'],
['StackOverflow']]
```

And I can do that with:

```
>>> np.sum(x.astype(object), axis = 1)
array(['HappyNewYear', 'StackOverflow'], dtype=object)
```

### *But how do I achieve concatenation with a separator?*

```
[['Happy New Year'],
['Stack Over flow']]
```

But can't seem to find a way without `loops (comprehensions), map, or apply_along_axis`. Is there an `in-built` function in numpy that can do this?

Found a [`join`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.chararray.join.html#numpy.chararray.join) method in `np.char.array` but it doesn't seem to work as I expected.

```
>>> x = np.char.array(x)
>>> x.join('')
array([['', '', ''],
       ['', '', '']], dtype='<U1')
>>> x.join(x)
array([['HHappyaHappypHappypHappyy', 'NNeweNeww', 'YYeareYearaYearr'],
       ['SStacktStackaStackcStackk', 'OOvervOvereOverr', 'fflowlflowofloww']], dtype='<U25')
```

Or,

```
>>> np.char.join(' ',x)
array([['H a p p y', 'N e w', 'Y e a r'],
       ['S t a c k', 'O v e r', 'f l o w']], dtype='<U9')
```

`np.sum(x, axis=1)` doesn't work, which is surprising to me, given this works:

```
>>> x[:,0] + x[:,1] + x[:,2]
chararray(['HappyNewYear', 'StackOverflow'], dtype='<U15')
```

I didn't find any question here that answers my issue exactly. Can someone help me out?

**EDIT**: I am really going for speed here, if this is achievable in `pandas` that would do as well.

**EDIT 2**:
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51190740/reduce-multi-dimensional-array-of-strings-along-axis-in-numpy) does not answer mine, as it uses comprehensions or uses lists as rows for the array, which I can't afford.

Comment: Python `join` is the cleanest way joining a list of strings.  I would just iterate over the rows.  When dealing strings, the numpy methods aren't any faster.  Do some time tests.  The no loop magic only applies to numeric operations.

Comment: Would pandas help? I will add the pandas tag if it helps.

Comment: pandas uses object dtype for strings - so its strings are python strings, not numpy 'U' dtypes.

Comment: Your sum as object trick uses the python string plus method.

Comment: pandas way : `pd.DataFrame(x).agg(' '.join,1).to_numpy()` :  would this help? though we have to check since the dtypes are converted to `object` as mentioned in an above comment

Comment: I hope it would. I am a little reluctant to introduce `pandas` if I can do with `numpy`, unless `pandas` gives major improvement. I would need to perform some testing. I am sure this must be better than loop based approaches. I would need to test all the methods some more as @hpaulj said.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reduce multi-dimensional array of strings along axis in Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51190740/reduce-multi-dimensional-array-of-strings-along-axis-in-numpy)

Comment: @Georgy It does not. It uses comprehension, or uses `list`s as rows for the array, which I can't afford.

Comment: For loops are not blanket bad , the pandas method is slower than a list comprehension according to my tests. besides check @hpaulj first comment. But then `timeit` is your friend here :)

Comment: @anky_91 yes, that;s what I am trying. Also I figured as I have ~100 cols and ~10**5 rows, I guess iterating over the columns and do this `x[:,i] + x[:,i+1] + x[:,i+2] + ...` wouldn't be that bad either, even though I asked for no loops in the question. But yeah, I get your point, I guess I should spend some more time measuring different approaches. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
x = x.astype(object)
x[:,:-1] += ' '
x.sum(axis=1).reshape(-1, 1)
```

Output:

```
array([['Happy New Year'],
       ['Stack Over flow']], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Yeah, thought of this just before your answer, don't know why it didn't come to mind while I was writing the question. Any reason you used `x[:,:-1] += ' '` as opposed to `x += ' '`?

Comment: @SayandipDutta With `x += ' '` you add `' '` also to the last column.

Answer (score 3):

You can always add a space then strip:

```
>>> np.char.array(np.sum(x.astype(object) + ' ', axis = 1)).strip().astype(str)
chararray(['Happy New Year', 'Stack Over flow'], 
      dtype='<U16')
>>>
```

Comment: Cool! I guess it's faster than explicit iterative techniques. Gotta do some testing.